# why the circle is getting drawn in a wrong place

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, size

I have an ImageView with its own background. I am trying to draw a circle in a point but the position of the circle is not right. for example I draw the circle in 0,0 but it is not on the top left of the background. what is the problem with my code?

moreover I need the bitmap size be the same as imageview but when I implement imageView.getWidth or .getHeight in the app for creating the bitmap, the app will crash! how to set the size of bitmap the same as the size of Imageview?!
thanks

```
    private void createBitMap() {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  //creates bmp
    bitMap = bitMap.copy(bitMap.getConfig(), true);     //lets bmp to be mutable
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitMap);                 //draw a canvas in defined bmp

    Paint paint = new Paint();                          //define paint and paint color
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    //paint.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);                           //smooth edges

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
    //changed set image resource to set image background resource
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.map);
    canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, 3, paint);
    //invalidate to update bitmap in imageview
    imageView.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: size of ImageView depends on size of Bitmap but not vice versa if width and height of ImageView are not hardcoded...

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have not added any Padding to the imageView in your xml layout. {Your code looks fine otherwise}

To stretch the image to match your imageView add this code to your ImageView of your layout file:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need the canvas be the same size of the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
    private void createBitMap() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        // this gives a mutable bitmap. no need to mutate it again...
        Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitMap); // draw a canvas in defined bmp

        Paint paint = new Paint(); // define paint and paint color
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        // paint.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true); // smooth edges
        canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, 3, paint);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
        // changed set image resource to set image background resource
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.map);
    }
```